# A Memory buffer for multiple images

Tags: c, image

I receive images on the PC from two cameras. The stream is not continuous but takes place at event detection. Therefore, I have to receive around 8-10 image pairs after a particular time. Since I have to process the images, I want to first keep all the images in a large buffer and later process them in a batch. It is also acceptable to keep images in two large buffers (one for each camera). How do I keep these pair of images in one (or two) large buffer(s)? I am implementing this program in C.

Comment: If you are implementing the program in C, why did you tag your question C++?

Comment: Not enough information.  Which OS? Which image library are you using.  Memory constraints?

Comment: I am working on UBUNTU. I am using only C functions to receive images via UDP and saving them (fwrite, i have still not integrated any image processing). BTW, I have enough memory to hold the images until they are processed/saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumeing the following API to get the image:

```
int ImageGet(
  char * pBuffer, 
  size_t * pSize); /* returns 0 on success or any other value if no image is available or on error */
```

you could do the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

...

#define IMAGESIZE_MAX (1024*1024) 

char * pBuffer = NULL;
char * pBufferCurrent = pBuffer;
int iResult = 0;
size_t size = IMAGESIZE_MAX;
size_t sizeTotal = 0;

do 
{
  char * pBufferCurrent = realloc (
    pBuffer, 
    sizeTotal + sizeof(size) + size);

  if (!pBufferCurrent)
  {
    break;
  }

  pBuffer = pBufferCurrent;

  pBufferCurrent += sizeTotal;

  if ((iResult = ImageGet (
    pBufferCurrent + sizeof(size), 
    &size))
  {
    break; 
  }

  memcpy (
    pBufferCurrent,
    &size, 
    sizeof(size));

  sizeTotal += (sizeof(size) + size);
} while (1);

...
```

This stores your data sequentially:

```
[     size 1     ][  image data 1  ][     size 2     ][  image data 2  ]...
<-sizeof(size_t)-><-    size 1    -><-sizeof(size_t)-><-    size 2    ->
```

in the buffer pointed to by `pBuffer`.

---

To retrieve a reference to the data describing image N from the buffer `pBuffer` you could use the following method:

```
const char * BufferImageGetByIndex(
    const char * pBuffer,
    unsigned indexImage)
{
  for (unsigned indexImageCnt = 0;
    indexImageCnt < indexImage;
    ++ indexImageCnt)
  {
    pBuffer += sizeof(size_t) + *((size_t *) pBuffer);
  }

  return pBuffer;
}
```

Then to actually get an image you could do like so:

```
...
/* Get a reference to the data decribing **fourth** image in the buffer filled by the example above. */
const char * pBufferImage4 = *BufferImageGetByIndex(pBuffer, 3);

/* Get the size ... */
size_t sizeImage4 = *((size_t *) pBufferImage4);
/* ... and a reference to the image data. */
const char * pImage4 = pBufferImage4 + sizeof(size_t);
...
```

Comment: One minor nitpick: Instead of defining IMAGESIZE_MAX to be a multiplication that needs to be evaluated at each check against the max, just make it the answer (1084576). Yeah it will be compiled as a simple 10-bit left shift, but there's no need to waste instructions willy-nilly.

Comment: I thought I might leave this as an exercise to the OP ... ;-) - no, to be honest I simply couldn't remember the result and I was too lazy start a calculator and even more to lazy too use my brain ... and I felt 1024 bytes might be unrealistic small for an image buffer these days @pg1989

Comment: No worries, I know the feeling all too well.

Comment: Btw: `IMAGESIZE_MAX` is only used **once**! :-) @pg1989

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. What I understand from your code is that if char *pBuffer is the pointer to a single image and size_t *pSize is its size, then every image will be stored sequentially separated by a length of 16 bytes (length of size_t). So When I read the images back from memory, I should point the pointer *pBuffer to the first image and increment it by *pBuffer+sizeof(size)+pBuffer. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To get the zeroth image read in `size_t size` from `*pBuffer`, increment `pBuffer` by `sizeof(size_t)` and then read `size` bytes of raw image data from `*pBuffer`; to get the next image increment `pBuffer` by the previously read `size` and start over (see my edited answer). Btw: `sizeof(size_t)` is expected to be 8 bytes on a recent version of Linux. @user846400

Comment: Any compiler worth it's salt will see no difference between (1024*1024) and (1048576).   It will recognize that (1024*1024) is invariant and optimize it accordingly.  It will not waste instructions calculating it **ever**. (By the way, 1084576 != (1024*1024) )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your images are all of a standard size and format, you can simply malloc() a buffer which will hold all the images at event detection time. If you're looking to do any analytics on the images, I would recommend switching to C++ and using the OpenCV libraries. They are pretty much without parallel in open-source image libs.

Comment: i use a single buffer (unsigned char* buffer) to receive a single image via UDP. The question is how do I use a buffer that can store multiple images?

Comment: Make it a bigger single buffer? I'm really confused as to what you're actually asking. Are you wondering what the best way to store the data in the buffer is?